# Why does Magento's API allow you to pull credit card information?

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I noticed Magento's API allows you to get order credit card information. Why is this an option?

Comment: I've been begging that we kill off that payment method, which is enabled by default.

Comment: I agree! It is a terrible thing to be enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it allows you to pull credit card information if case you are using the Saved credit card payment option for testing purposes. It has been suggested to not using the payment method in a live site or you site can be compromised.

It is simply for testing.

Comment: It seems silly to use it for testing. I don't thing it should exist. Thanks for the response. I thought it was for testing purposes.